# How to save bit fields from flag_shih_tzu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, bit-manipulation

I have the a model with flag_shih_tzu for saving few options as bitwise in one column. 
I succeed to show the data using :

<%= f.input :, as: :radio_buttons %> (as I have "yes/no")

When I try to save the form is not working since I got error : Can't mass-assign protected attributes:

Thanks a lot for help

daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the field to `attr_accessible`.